# Delete tableRows in tablelayout

Tags: android, xamarin, rows, tablelayout, dynamically-generated

I tried to delete rows in my tableLayout using:

- `table.RemoveAllViews()`
- `table.RemoveAllViewInLayout()`
- `table.RemoveViewAt()`

But it didn't work.

**All my rows are added dynamically.**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you paste the code?

Comment: edit your question to add additional details like your code and information about the timer and what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to clear all your table you can remove table childs one by one in *for* loop using:

```
int count = table.getChildCount();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    View child = table.getChildAt(i);
    table.removeView(child);
}
```